# Stop Matlab from using set methods when loading matlab.mixin.Copyable object?

Tags: matlab, oop

I have a classe derived from matlab.mixin.Copyable.  Some of the properties have `set` methods.  I want the setting of those properties to also update other properties so that the relationship between the parameters are consistent (a classic use of set methods).

Unfortunately, when I `load` a `*.mat` file [specifically using, say, `x=load('file.mat')`], setters are also used.  There should be no need for that kind of automatic update of multiple parameters, since all the object's properties can be copied from the *.mat file and self-consistency is automatically maintained.  Instead, using setters during `load` causes errors because the setter uses other properties that haven't yet been assigned to in the `load` process.  I see this from error that occurs during the `load`, and from checking the properties that are needed by the setter.

**Is there any way to force the `load` to do a simple replication of the property values contained the `*.mat` file?**  Some of the properties are complex objects themselves, so what's needed is a recursive copy-by-value during `load`.  It seems rather inappropriate to use setters during a `load`, for the reasons above.

P.S. I say above that the setter uses another as-yet-unassigned property.  Let's call this property `p2`.  It also gets assigned to by a setter for 3rd property `s1`.  It seemed odd, but `s1` *does* have a value, while `p2` does not.  One possible reason is that `p2` relies on other properties in addition to `s1`, and those might not have been assigned to when `s1` is loaded (i.e., when the `s1` setter is invoked).  The whole problem stems from the fact that `load` occurs outside of the context and the order in which properties are assigned to during the execution of the code that created it.  This is the key reason why (it seems to me that) `load` should *not* use setters.  Otherwise, it seems to be incompatible with either copying or loading (I'm not sure which at the moment -- maybe both).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process MATLAB uses to load objects is [well documented](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/understanding-the-save-and-load-process.html). This page mentions, among many other things, that the set methods are called to prevent issues that happen when a class definition changes, and you try to load an object from that class from an old file.

There is also a page explaining how to [modify the save and load process](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/modifying-the-save-and-load-process.html). This page describes the use of [`loadobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadobj.html), defined as a static method to your class, to change how the object is constructed from the information in the file. `loadobj` is called when one of the `set` methods throws an error; but it is always called if `saveobj` returns a struct. That is, one solution to your problem is to have `saveobj` create a struct with all the data, and have `loadobj` reconstruct your object from that struct.

[This other documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/avoiding-property-initialization-order-dependency.html) describes how to design your class to avoid property initialization order dependency -- which is the problem you describe having. The way to do this is to have all public properties be dependent properties, with the "actual" data properties being hidden and not interdependent. You might be able to construct your class this way, for example with a single data property (a cell array or struct), which would be loaded and saved in one go, and the public properties simply using a portion of this cell or struct in the set and get methods.

Comment: Thanks, Cris.  You're right, this is well documented.  It just doesn't come up with my google-fu.  I will try to avoid replanning my class, as it is already in a relatively mature app.  Plus, my properties often are dependent and independent, which is the effect I wanted.  I just didn't realize that it would be incompatible with `load`.

Comment: I will take a closer look at loadobj and saveobj, but even if I figure out the in's and out's, I suspect there are other dragons lurking, e.g., some properties are handles to large objects.  I might be able to re-assign these after the `load`, but it starting to get further and further away from a single-statement `load` -- which is what I need, as I am using it in the context of debugging, and don't want to be bogged down by design issues to work around `load` complications.  It may be time to rethink the debugging instead.